# how to build object from mmapped memory

Tags: c

I am building a custom allocator. I am calling `mmap()` the first time and then I am constructing an explicit freelist. Everything works fine, but when I need to split an existing block I do not seem to be able to initialize an object from a void* (my C fundamentals are quite rusty). I know it sounds confusing so here is the code that I have.

```
// this is the struct I am using to keep track of the free nodes
struct Node {
   size_t header;
   void* payload;
}
```

when I split, I decrease the size of the big node

```
void* split_block(Node* good_node, size_t reqsize) {
    DECREASE_SIZE(good_node)
    Node* prev_node = (Node*)(good_node -> payload);
    Node* next_node = (Node*)((good_node -> payload) + 8);
}
```

I store the pointers to next and previous node. IMPORTANT, the pointer are inside the payload, specifically `prev = payload`, `next=payload+8`.
Now the problem. How do I construct a node from the raw memory (payload).
The code that does not work is this

```
// I omit the calculation of the address at which 
// the split_part is going to end up

Node* split_part = GET_HEADER_POSITION(good_node, reqsize);
split_part->header = some_value;
split_part->payload = prev_node;
split_part->payload[1] = next_node;
```

I did not construct the object. But how can I do so, should not this work just like when I malloc memory?

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: What does "initialize an object from a void*" mean? There is no object construction in C. Are you thinking of C++?

Comment: What I mean is to access the fields of a struct with arrow notation. however the node as you can see is not initialized. How can I set the fields of the node?

Comment: uh... `node->header = some_value;`?

Comment: my crystal balls says you don't realize that `void *payload;` is a pointer and therefore can point anywhere in memory, and that you don't set it to point to a useful place.

Comment: node->header does not work

Comment: how doesn't it work?